# Why I get TypeError when counting visits with Flask?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a problem when counting visits on a view in my Flask app:
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'int'`

I know what it means but I don't understand why in this case.

Right now, I'm just doing this by simply incrementing the `note.visits` value I get from my database in a method:

```py
@bp.route('/view/<int:id>')
def view(id):
    note = Notes.query.get_or_404(id)
    note.visits += 1
    db.session.commit()
    note.owner_id = str(note.owner_id)
    return render_template('notes/view.html', note=note)
```

In my model, I defined this field like :

```py
visits = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)
```

It's working everytime but I get the error in my stackstraces.

Thank's for help !

Comment: Something is a amiss with your get_or_404 if it's returning None. Can you post a complete working example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it!

I added that `visits` field in the last migration.
The notes that already existed had nothing on this field.
I updated those old notes and the problem is gone.
From now, all notes will have a visits field configured to 0 by default.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'int`'

This exception means that `note.visits` is `None`, and you can't use the `+=` operator with `None` objects.

Comment: How could it be `None` since I have visits numbers in my database and increment is working...

Comment: That's hard to say without debugging the code... but the error it's damn clear and can't be otherwise